# Advantages of using either EXTRACT() or YEAR()

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Is there any performance difference when using `EXTRACT()` over `YEAR()` (or `MONTH()`, `DAY()`, etc) and vice versa. When should you use one over the other?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I doubt that there would be any notable difference in any database.  They are doing the same thing.

Comment: I usually say stick to ANSI SQL to write portable code. In this case that's `EXTRACT()`, but too many products don't support it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: not all databases supports both syntax - as an example:

- SQL Server supports `YEAR()`/`MONTH()`/`DAY()` but not `EXTRACT()` (you need `DATEPART()` instead)
- Postgres supports `EXTRACT()` but not the short forms

So the actual answer might depend on the database that you are actually using

But as a general answer, I would not expect any difference. `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DAY()` are just syntactical sugars for `EXTRACT(YEAR/MONTH/DAY FROM ...)`.

Comment: oh ok, got it, I'm using MYSQL. I thought there's going to be a performance difference between the two.